# Article or no article. The word "Stage"

Tags: articles, zero-article, dictionaries

How to understand whether it is necessary to put the article before this word and before other words like this?
Dictionaries like this([enter link description here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/stage_1?q=stage)) don't give explanations or something I don't understand.

> The audience on ***the*** stage. People on stage.
>
> There were over 50 people on stage. There were 50 people on ***the*** stage.

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**on stage**, **onstage** and **on the stage** are very similar. In everyday life, you can use any.

**on stage** and **onstage** usually refer to the general setup where an artist goes to a place (e.g. theater) to give a performance.

**on the stage** refers to the specific place, usually a raised platform, where the artist will stand / sit / dance... during the performance